# How to add a new taxonomy link to the admin menu

Tags: plugin-development

I am looking to add a new admin menu item from my plugin call "Tickers" under "Post", with the link similar to "Tags", but point to

```
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=tickers
```

What I have so far is

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'admin_menu'));
function admin_menu () {
     add_options_page();    
}
```

I am not sure what are the right parameters to pass to add_options_page.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

Answer provided below lead me to http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-taxonomy/, which can generate the custom taxonomy functions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxonomy admin page will be handled by WordPress once you register your custom taxonomy.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_ticker_taxonomies', 0 );

//create two taxonomies, genres and writers for the post type "book"
function create_ticker_taxonomies() {

  // Add new taxonomy, make it non-hierarchical (like 'tags')
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Tickers', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    ...
  );    

  register_taxonomy('ticker',array('post'), array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
  ));
}
```

The full options available to you regardin the taxonomy and its labels can be found on the [Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).